# how to get dynamic table row data onclick of a button within table in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table

i'm using dynamic table with each row having a button, on click of a button, i need data of the respective row button clicked.

I've tried (click) event binding on  and i get output as undefined.

```html
<table>
<thead> <tr> <th> Name </th> <th> Company </th> </tr> </thead>
<tr *ngFor = "let employee of employees" (click) = "removeEmployee(row)">
            <td> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "employee.name"></td>
            <td> <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "employee.companyName"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

.ts file

```js
removeEmployee(tr) {
      console.log(tr);
    }
```

expected: on click of button, table row data should output.

actual: undefined is displayed.

Comment: You should pass employee to function removeEmployee instead of row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change row in employee:

```
<tr *ngFor = "let employee of employees" (click) = "removeEmployee(employee)">
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. How to get rowIndex of respective row as well?

Comment: <tr *ngFor = "let employee of employees; let idx = index" (click) = "removeEmployee(employee)">

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution for it

```
<table>
<thead> <tr> <th> Name </th> <th> Company </th> </tr> </thead>
<tr *ngFor = "let employee of employees" (click) = "removeEmployee(employee)">
            <td> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "employee.name"></td>
            <td> <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "employee.companyName"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

.ts file

```
removeEmployee(tr) {
      console.log(tr);
    }
```